# python: walrus operator and re.search() in list comprehension

Tags: python, walrus-operator

I have a list of strings and I want to extract a pattern from  elements.

For instance, given list `["A 12345bcd", "BYT 676 CCC"]` and pattern `r'\d\d\d\d\d'`, I would like to obtain: ["12345", ""]

I know how to do without it, but I want to use walrus operator `:=`.

I tried:

`[(m:=re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', x), m.group() if m else "") for x in ["A 12345bcd", "BYT 676 CCC"]]`

But the result is:

`[(<re.Match object; span=(2, 7), match='12345'>, '12345'), (None, '')]`

Hence, not what I want

Comment: Then don't do that. You have built a list comprehension which returns a tuple for each iteration; why do you do that if what you want is something else?

Comment: `(m := re.search(…)) and m.group()`…

Comment: As an aside, `r'\d{5}'` would be a more readable regex IMHO.

Comment: @deceze I guess you need an `or` to produce an empty string instead of `None` too.

Comment: @deceze: this works (almost) like intended. Almost becuse second element is None, but I can live with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tuple:

```
(m:=re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', x), m.group() if m else "")
```

This is the `group`/empty conditional expression with `m :=` evaluated appropriately early:

```
m.group() if (m := re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d', x)) else ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

l = ["A 12345bcd", "BYT 676 CCC"]

result = [(res := re.search(r"\d{5}", x)) and res.group() or "" for x in l]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['12345', '']
```